# Robot framework - Test suite output in json format

Tags: python, json, robotframework

```
pybot --output abc.json test.robot
```

The above command renders the output in xml format. Does pybot support getting the summary output in json format?

Similarly, does `rebot` command consolidate the output files that are in `json` format like,

```
rebot --log log.html --report  report.html --output output.json final_output.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robot generates only XML, and can convert that XML to HTML. If you need data in JSON format you'll have to do the conversion yourself.